# Control JAX-RS application startup

Tags: java, maven, jax-rs, pom.xml

First of all I'm new to JAX-RS. I'm trying to create a backend, and I've went for the pom.xml implementation. To be more specific I have this class

```java
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("webapi")
public class MyApp extends Application {

}
```

and I want to know how to control when it's being started up and eventually stop it from starting up.

Some thing like this:

```java
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("webapi")
public class MyApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onStartup() {
        if (!Utils.isConfDataValid()) 
            exit(1);
    }

}
```

I just have now idea about any Application events, or anything like that in JAX-RS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that certain types of events or hooks are web-application server dependant.
In this case `JAX-RS` has no part in what you're looking for.

Note also that I don't recommend using `System.exit` or terminating an application like that.

---

Being that `JAX-RS` is based in the `Servlet` stack, you can register a `ServletContextListener` implementation to execute code on context start-up.

```
public class CustomServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
   @Override
   public void contextInitialized(final ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
      // Context startup
   }

   @Override
   public void contextDestroyed(final ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
      // Context shutdown
   }
}
```

This listener can be registered by annotating it with `@WebListener` if you're on a `Servlet 3+` environment

```
@WebListener
public class CustomServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
```

Otherwise you need to use the old fashioned `web.xml` file, as `<listener-class>`.

Comment: Thanks! Can I manually stop the application somehow? Or, at least, restrict it from starting up?

Comment: @CosminStoian You could throw a RuntimeException (this is application-server dependant). Or, you could set a parameter and inspect it inside a Filter, which returns an error message with the cause. You'd need to manually restart it anyway (or ask a container to do that).